# modem didn't respond to AT commends

Tags: windows-10, serial-port, usb-modem

I want to perform some AT commends on my huawei ec122 modem (locked)
but i didn't receive any response from it.
i am using c# to perform request with waterline method
the port open without problem and my request are send successfully.
i know that because i installed wireshark and i guaranteed that my request are send to the correct COM port that modem original application communicate with.

```
port = new SerialPort("COM13");  
port.Open();
port.WriteLine("AT");           //Get the modem's attention
port.WriteLine("ATI");          // Get All Manufacturer Info
port.WriteLine("AT+CGMM");      // Get USB Model
port.WriteLine("AT+CGMI");      // Manufacturer
port.WriteLine("AT+CIMI");      // Get SIM IMSI number
port.WriteLine("AT+CGSN");      //Get modem IMEI
port.WriteLine("AT+CGMR");
```

i didn't post this on stack because i don't think it have something to do with code, i suspect that it have to do with the modem been locked, and i need to guaranteed that.
what do you suggest for me to do ?
thanks.

Comment: "All" modems I have tried required CR+LF  ("\r\n" = \x0d0a), not just CR or LF. Does "x.WriteLine()" provide that? Also: You must wait for the answer before sending next command.

Comment: i found a code that's working but i didn't understand yet why mine didn't, i will report when a understand the issue, thanks for your help